# Por qué no puedo volver una pagina que ya he abierto en shiny?

Tags: r, rstudio, shiny

tengo una aplicacion en shiny con varios indicadores distribuidas en varias paginas, el problema es que si abro una pagina y luego otra, no puedo volver a abrir la primera, hay alguna forma de solucionarlo?

Por favor sigan las siguientes instrucciones para reproducir el problema

clic a2, clic b1, clic c1, clic c8 y clic de nuevo en c1 (no podemos volver a ver la informacion en c1)

ui.R

```
library(shinydashboard)
library(shiny)

sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(

    tags$head(tags$style(HTML('.content-wrapper { height: 1500px !important;}'))),

    hr(),

    sidebarMenu(id="tabs",
                menuItem("a1", tabName="principal", icon=icon("pagelines"), selected=TRUE),
                menuItem("a2", icon=icon("chart-bar"),
                         menuSubItem("b1", tabName = "identificacion", icon = icon("angle-right")),
                         menuSubItem("b2", tabName = "comunicacion", icon = icon("angle-right")),
                         menuSubItem("b3", tabName = "medicamentos", icon = icon("angle-right")),
                         menuSubItem("b4", tabName = "cirugias", icon = icon("angle-right")),
                         menuSubItem("b5", tabName = "infecciones", icon = icon("angle-right")),
                         menuSubItem("b6", tabName = "caidas", icon = icon("angle-right"))
                ),
                menuItem("a3", tabName = "procesos", icon=icon("chart-bar")),
                menuItem("a4", tabName = "tiempos", icon = icon("chart-bar")),
                menuItem("a5", tabName = "manual", icon=icon("mortar-board")),
                menuItem("a6", tabName = "acerca", icon = icon("question"))
    ),width = 285,

    hr(),

    conditionalPanel("input.tabs=='identificacion'",
                     fluidRow(
                         column(1),
                         column(10,
                                menuItem("c1", tabName="admision_iden", icon=icon("chart-line"), selected=FALSE),
                                menuItem("c8", tabName="uci_iden", icon=icon("chart-line"), selected=FALSE)
                         )
                     )
    ))

body <- dashboardBody(
    tabItems(

        tabItem(tabName = "principal",
                withMathJax(),("example of text")),

        tabItem(tabName = "admision_iden", titlePanel("example1"),"example of text 2"),

        tabItem(tabName = "uci_iden", titlePanel("example 2"),"example of text 3")))



dashboardPage(
    dashboardHeader(title = "Indic", titleWidth=285),
    sidebar,
    body
)
```

server.R

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
shinyServer(function(input, output) {

})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te sugiero dos cambios a tu código que deberían solucionar el problema:

1. El `conditionalPanel()` tiene estar dentro del `sidebarMenu()`, sino no hay forma que funcionen los tabs. Es decir

   ```
   sidebarMenu(id="tabs",
               ....
               menuItem("a6", tabName = "acerca", icon = icon("question")),
               conditionalPanel("input.tabs == 'identificacion' || input.tabs == 'admision_iden' || input.tabs == 'uci_iden'",
                           fluidRow(column(1),
                                    column(10,
                                    menuItem("c1", tabName="admision_iden", icon=icon("chart-line"), selected=FALSE),
                                    menuItem("c8", tabName="uci_iden", icon=icon("chart-line"), selected=FALSE)
                                    )
                                )
               )
       ),width = 285
   )
   ```
2. Es fundamental verificar que se den todas las condiciones para que se active el panel: `"input.tabs == 'identificacion' || input.tabs == 'admision_iden' || input.tabs == 'uci_iden'"` es decir que se active con cualquiera de estos tres tabs, si solo tienes el tab principal, con el primer click se ocultaría el panel.

Comment: Don Patricio, muchisimas gracias por su tiempo. Me funciona como deseaba. Saludos.